# How to Save MATLAB GUI state

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

When constructing a GUI, sometimes it would be appropriate for the GUI to start in the last state it was in when it was closed. I mean the same values selected in list boxes, radio buttons, and so on. How could we do that?

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/

Comment: Thanks for the video!